# Unit testing writing to a socket in scala

Tags: scala, sockets, mockito, serversocket, scalatest

I have the following code that given a socket, writes content to the socket and based on that returns a `Right` or `Left`

```
class Gateway {
  def sendEvent(
                 str: String,
                 socket: Socket): Either[CustomException, String] = {
    Try {
      val writer =
        new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream))


      writer.write(s"${str}\n")
      writer.flush()
    } match {
      case Success(_) => Right(str)
      case Failure(_) => Left(CustomException)
    }
  }
}
```

I am trying to unit test the `sendEvent` method. However the line

```
new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream))
```

prevents me from doing so. Now, I cannot pass in BufferedWriter as a dependency as I need to open a new connection always.

I am using `Scalatest` and `Mockito` for testing. Any ideas on how to unit test this code will be highly appreciated. Thanks in advance !!!

Comment: You SHOULD `close` writer in finally block (`close` commonly call `flush`). In this case, you may prefer use `try-catch-finaly` block instead of `Try-match` block. IMHO, you should replace unit test on integration test, or use `OutputStream` instead of `Socket`. You can add additional method wtih Socket in this case. May be there is test library that allow you overwrite `getOutputStream`.

Answer (score 1):

I think that there is no point in unit-testing this class other than having a beautiful test coverage report.

This code in my opinion should rather be indirectly covered by an integration test for a bigger module.

If you really want to test it in isolation I'd spin-up a local test server in a test and send messages to it.

Such test would rather verify you understanding of a socket workflow rather than the business logic.